# How can I hide code blocks in xaringan presentation?

Tags: css, r, xaringan

I'm running some plot code in markdown to generate a plot in a xaringan presentation. The code works but is a little long and so takes up the whole presentation slide forcing the actual plot off the edge (see img).

How can I hide the code block generating the plot?

Also how can I compress the code block with a scroll bar?

[image: output]

````
```{r}
r_exp.fun <- function(r = 0.05, N_pop = 10, t = 150)
{
  N <- vector("numeric", length = t)
  N[1] <- N_pop
  for (i in 2:t)
  {
    N[i] <- N[i-1] + (N[i-1] * r)
  }
  return(N)
}

args_list <- list(0.045, 0.055, 0.06)

matplot(
  mapply(
    r_exp.fun,
    r = args_list
  )
  ,type = "l")
abline(h = list(7052, 29150, 59000))
```
````

The alternative is of course to save as an image but if possible I would prefer to be able keep the code as a resource for anyone with the link.

Thanks!

Comment: It's RMarkdown, so put `echo=FALSE` in the chunk header (e.g. `{r plot-chunk, echo=FALSE}`). Docs: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results

Comment: oh, that was easy, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As alistaire already mentioned in the comments, RMarkdown has various chunk options to customize the output.
For your problem the option `echo` needs to be set to `FALSE`.

The other options (from https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html):

```
include = FALSE
```

prevents code and results from appearing in the finished file. R Markdown still runs the code in the chunk, and the results can be used by other chunks.

```
echo = FALSE
```

prevents code, but not the results from appearing in the finished file. This is a useful way to embed figures.

```
message = FALSE
```

prevents messages that are generated by code from appearing in the finished file.

```
warning = FALSE
```

prevents warnings that are generated by code from appearing in the finished.

```
fig.cap = "..."
```

adds a caption to graphical results.

Comment: Thanks. Really useful to know the extra options.